# nexttick callback and promise callback are not output as expected

Tags: node.js, promise

I want to try this code

```
process.nextTick(() => console.log(8)) 
Promise.resolve("hi").then(t => console.log(t)) 
console.log(7);
```

The expected output is

```
7
8
hi
```

but my output is

```
7
hi
8
```

I'm familiar with event loop in nodejs, but have no clue why it is not work as expected.
I also use other online compiler, and they all output the expected one.
ex.https://onecompiler.com/nodejs/3yyc9qc65

If someone occur this situation, or understand my environment has something wrong, please let me know.

my Node.js version is 19.6.0.

The environment is code-server 4.9.1 using docker and the server is on unraid 6.11.5.

Comment: I've run the code on my machine and my output is 7, 8, hi respectively. My current node version is 18.12.1

Comment: IIRC the ordering of `nextTick` callbacks depends a lot on in which tick the `nextTick()` function was called. How exactly are you running this code? Is this your whole code? And is there an actual problem this causes or is it just academic curiousity?

Comment: Yes, this is my whole code. And the problem exists. I try this snippet on other environments, and they all output the right order.

Comment: So again, where and how are you running this? In a module? In a script? In the REPL?

Comment: I'm running this on code server, and type is in module.

Comment: Okey, now I acknowledge that this problem is due to the type I choose, after I remove the type selection in package.json, the output is correct now. But I have no idea why type is associate with this problem?